How can I prevent watermarks on oiled kitchen worktops?
I have recently sanded my beech wood kitchen worktops down so I could re-oil them to freshen them up.
I applied clear Ronseal worktop oil after sanding.
I gave it 3 coats, 24 hours between each coat, and gave it a good 36 hours between the last coat and using the worktop to make sure it was bone dry.
Unfortunately, it now gets water marks really easily.
Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could do to prevent this?
I don’t really want to have to sand the whole thing down to use a different product if I can help it. I followed the instructions on precisely.

This questions is probably more appropriate on the woodworking sister site https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Might need to seal the top.  Does ronseal recommend any sealers?  Sealing wood and sealing the finish might be two different things, or I am blowing smoke.

Too late now, but I'd recommend a tung oil finish instead.  I gave our butcher block island a Hope's tung oil finish and every time I think my wife is going to leave a water stain (or almost any kind of stain), it just wipes off.
